# yii2 консоль Unknown command

Tags: yii2, консоль

Пытаюсь запустить action в контроллере, который расположен в /console/modules/googleanalytics/controllers, но получаю ошибку:

```
Unknown command: googleanalytics/import/all-for-time
```

в console/config/main.php прописано:

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\FixtureController',
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
          ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                    'logVars' => [],
                    'categories' => ['calls'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/calls.log',
                    'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                    'maxLogFiles' => 20,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'modules'=>[
        'user-management' => [
            'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule',
            'controllerNamespace'=>'vendor\webvimark\modules\UserManagement\controllers', // To prevent yii help from crashing
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Текст команды:

```
./yii googleanalytics/import/all-for-time  '2017-02-27' '2017-02-27'
```

Что я делаю не так? Может надо поменять 'controllerNamespace' в конфигах?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в конфиг модуль **googleanalytics**, yii просто не видит его а потому и не может запустить

```
'modules'=>[
    'user-management' => [
        'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule',
        'controllerNamespace'=>'vendor\webvimark\modules\UserManagement\controllers', // To prevent yii help from crashing
    ],
    'googleanalytics' => [
       'class' => ...
    ]
],
```

Comment: теперь отрабатывается, но не может найти класс Google_Client

Comment: а что конкретно пишет?